# Can I setup plain hadoop not HDP with apache ambari

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I have seen many tutorials for Ambari, all uses HDP stack from hortonworks so I want to know I can setup plain hadoop cluster without HDP.

Can I setup Hadoop using Ambari without HDP?

Comment: HDP is plain old hadoop... Hortonworks has done all the work for you and taken each service in hadoop and defined a service for it in Ambari. These service descriptions are what allow Ambari to provision, manage, and monitor the cluster for you. Maybe you can tell us why you don't want to use  the HDP stack for us to better answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

To set up a 'plain' Hadoop cluster, you will have to define your own stack definition to work with Ambari.

Documentation on how to setup your own stack and services can be found here [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/How-To+Define+Stacks+and+Services).

**Additional Note:** There are efforts from [ODPi](https://www.odpi.org/) to make management of custom stacks and services through Ambari standardized.